# Format partitions 5 and 6 when installing?

Tags: 14.04

When I want to install alongside windows 7 before I install it said its going to format #5 partition and #6 partition What does this do if I already have an unallocated space for it to go? does this delete anything important? I have ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Choose Try Ubuntu first then use Gparted. Remember to unmount drive first. Once done - used install option on desktop